# Change locale dynamically according to a dynamic currency value

Tags: java, locale, currency, currency-formatting

End-users are provided with a list of currencies. One of which of their interest may be selected by them at any time. As such, a locale used in `java.text.NumberFormat` needs to be changed based on the currency selected. This does not appear to be trivial.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
NumberFormat decimalFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
decimalFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
decimalFormat.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("USD"));

System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.12)));
```

The piece of code above will display the correct currency value `$1.12`. Since currency (and locale) is determined dynamically at run-time based on the user's preference, if `USD` is changed to something different like `GBP`, then the associated locale  also needs to be changed from `en_US` to `en_GB`. Otherwise, it will display `GBP1.12` where `£1.12` is expected (the currency rate is excluded for brevity).

Is there a way to determine the locale based on the currency code which is supplied dynamically at run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only support a limited number of currencies then you are probably better off creating the mapping manually. Otherwise it's going to be difficult because there is more than one valid locale per currency. For example USD can be `en_US` or `es_US` or `es_PR` or `es_EC`...

You can look at `Currency.getInstance(locale)` for all `Locale.availableLocales()` to get an idea:

```
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
  try {
    Currency c = Currency.getInstance(locale);
    System.out.println(c + "\t" + locale);
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignore) { }
}
```